# RSA sign in OPENSSL

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, rsa, sign

I am trying to sign a message with a RSA private key. I read a private key to pkey and then sign a string as what says on openssl wiki, but failed in the final step. It always returns 0 on the line commented in program, which means sign failed. Could anyone helps me find out what’s wrong?

```
void main() {

EVP_MD_CTX * mdctx ;
EVP_PKEY * pkey ;
char dmessage[20] = "The messages";
int ret = 0;
FILE * fp;
unsigned char * sig = NULL;
size_t * slen = malloc(sizeof(size_t));

fp = fopen ("privkey.pem", "r");
if (fp == NULL) exit (1);
pkey = PEM_read_PrivateKey(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
fclose (fp);

if (pkey == NULL) { 
  ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
exit (1);
}

if(!(mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create())) goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignInit(mdctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, pkey)) goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mdctx, dmessage, 12)) goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, NULL, slen)) goto err;
if(!(sig = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (int)(*slen)))) goto err;
if(1 != (ret = EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, sig, slen))) goto err;//*****it return 0 here,which means sign failed

ret = 1;
err:
if(ret != 1)
{
  printf("%d somthing wrong\n",ret);
}

/* Clean up */
if(sig && !ret) OPENSSL_free(sig);
if(mdctx) EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
return;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

I’m using openssl 1.0.1j on linux mint 17, and the private key is generated by

```
openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is way too small, that's bits not bytes. Try again with a good secure key size that can hold the hash and PKCS#1 padding. I would recommend at least 2048 bits instead of the 256 bits that you generated using the OpenSSL command line.

See [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com) for more information about key sizes. Note that RSA requires a key size a lot larger than those required for symmetric algorithms such as AES.